# How to use on board LED of rasberry pi pico w CircuitPython

Tags: pi-pico-w

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi Pico W and I'm eager to experiment with it. I planned on writing a program to blink an LED, but I discovered that unlike the Pi Pico, the Pi Pico W doesn't work on Pi 25. After reading some articles, I discovered that the LED on the Pi Pico W is connected to the wifi module. I'm curious if there is a way to use the onboard LED for my blinking program. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the PicoW documentation the differences are discussed in detail.

Try https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/multilingual-blink-for-raspberry-pi-pico/ for a start.

The following python code works (using MicroPython):-

```
import machine
import utime
# 3.4. The on-board LED Connecting to the Internet with Raspberry Pi Pico W
led = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)

utime.sleep(5)
while True:
    led.toggle()
    utime.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This video shows in detail how you can control the on board LED of Raspberry Pi PicoW using circuitpython.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56N_8FI_WLU